# I cannot insert three images using php into a mysql database

Tags: php, file-upload

I am newbie to php and it's my first work..actually I have created a "insert product" page, it has three images.... This page is connected to database... 
when I insert three images it does not alert "product inserted" but when I remove last two images.. it inserts successfully...
thank you for your help..
Here is the code___________________

```
        <form action="insert_product.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="700" align="center" border="1" bgcolor="#3398ce">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2"><h2>Insert New Product:</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Title</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Category</b></td>
                    <td>    
                        <select name="product_cat">
                            <option>Select a Category</option>
                            <?php
                            $sel_cats ="select * from categories";
                            $run_cats =mysqli_query($con, $sel_cats)
                            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
                            while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                            $cat_id =$row_cats['cat_id'];
                            $cat_title=$row_cats['cat_title'];
                            echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";


                }
                ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td align="right"><b>Product Brand</b></td>
                    <td>
                         <select name="product_brand">
                            <option>Select a Brand</option>
                            <?php
            $sel_brands ="select * from brands";
            $run_brands =mysqli_query($con, $sel_brands)
             or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
            while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
                $brand_id =$row_brands['brand_id'];
                $brand_title=$row_brands ['brand_title'];
               echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";


                }

                ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 1</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img1"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 2</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img2"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Image 3</b></td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="product_img3"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Price</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_price" size="20"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Description</b> </td>
                    <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="37" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="80"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="insert_product" value="Insert" size="50"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
    //text data variables//
    $product_title =$_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat =$_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand =$_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price =$_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc =$_POST['product_desc'];
    $status = 'on';
    $product_keywords=$_POST['product_keywords'];


    //image data variables//
    $product_img1 =$_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
    $product_img2 =$_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
    $product_img3 =$_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

    //image temp names//
    $temp_name1 =$_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 =$_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 =$_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

    if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1==''){

        echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields!')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"images/$product_img1");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"images/$product_img2");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"images/$product_img3");

    $insert = "insert into products(cat_id,brand_id,date,product_title,product_img1,product_img2,product_img3,product_price,product_desc,status,product_keywords) values
    ('$product_cat','$product_brand',NOW(),'$product_title','$product_img1','$product_img2','$product_img3','$product_price','$product_desc','$status','$product_keywords')";
    $run_product =mysqli_query($con, $insert);
    if($run_product){
        echo "<script>alert('Product Inserted')</script>";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

---

can anyone help in syntax error.....
bro can you guess the syntax error here $product_img1 =$_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
        $product_img2 =$_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
        $product_img3 =$_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

```
    //image size varibles//
     $pro_img1_size = $_FILES['product_img1']['size'];
     $pro_img2_size  = $_FILES['product_img2']['size'];
     $pro_img3_size  = $_FILES['product_img3']['size'];

     //image type variables//
     $pro_img1_type = $_FILES['product_img1']['type'];
     $pro_img2_type = $_FILES['product_img2']['type'];
     $pro_img3_type = $_FILES['product_img3']['type'];

    //image temp names//
    $temp_name1 =$_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 =$_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 =$_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

    if($product_title=='' OR $product_cat=='' OR $product_brand=='' OR $product_price=='' OR $product_desc=='' OR $product_keywords=='' OR $product_img1==''){

        echo "<script>alert('Please fill all the fields!')</script>";
        exit();
    }

    if($pro_img1_type=="product_img1/jpeg" OR $pro_img1_type=="product_img1/png" OR $pro_img1_type=="product_img1/gif" OR $pro_img2_type=="product_img2/jpeg" OR $pro_img2_type=="product_img2/png" OR $pro_img2_type=="product_img2/gif" OR $pro_img3_type=="product_img3/jpeg" OR $pro_img3_type=="product_img3/png" OR $pro_img3_type=="product_img3/gif")
    {
           if($pro_img1_size<=100000 AND $pro_img2_size<=100000 AND $pro_img3_size<=100000 ){
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"pro_images/$product_img1");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");
        }
           else {
                echo "<script>alert('Image is larger, only 100kb size is allowed')</script>";
                exit();
           }
                echo "<script>alert('Image type is invalid')</script>";
                exit();
           }
           else {

    $insert = "insert into products(cat_id,brand_id,date,product_title,product_img1,product_img2,product_img3,product_price,product_desc,status,product_keywords) values
    ('$product_cat','$product_brand',NOW(),'$product_title','$product_img1','$product_img2','$product_img3','$product_price','$product_desc','$status','$product_keywords')";
    $run_product =mysqli_query($con, $insert);
    if($run_product){
        echo "<script>alert('Product Inserted')</script>";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error you get ? are the images getting uploaded ?

Comment: files not being uploaded and also it does not echo "inserted" when i insert three images...

Answer (score 0):

print_r($_FILES);

Multiple image array is not like you have written.

First print the files array, you will get the error in your code.

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer. It could be commment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file size is within the default upload size limits set by php. The default size set by php for upload_max_filesize is "2M" if your image file is bigger than 2M that will cause issues. Perhaps the other two files you are trying to upload is bigger than 2M.

Comment: thank you very very much... this was the problem.. when did i limit size it inserted successfully...thanks again